GoRouter's state.pageKey.value is showing gibberish values
While working with GoRouter in Flutter, I was trying to debugPrint the page keys to see the checkout routing.
I did not do anything complicated.
Inside my GoRouter class
return GoRouter(
    initialLocation: '/',
    routes: [
    GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        name: AppRoute.home.name,
        builder: (context, state) => const ProductsScreen(),
        routes: [
        GoRoute(
            path: 'cart',
            name: AppRoute.cart.name, //this is just an enum value
            pageBuilder: (context, state) => const MaterialPage(
              fullscreenDialog: true,
              child: ShoppingCartScreen(),
            ),
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                  path: 'checkout',
                  name: AppRoute.checkout.name,
                  pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                    //Unreadable pageKey.value string here
                    debugPrint(state.pageKey.value);

                    return MaterialPage(
                      key: state.pageKey
                      child: const CheckoutScreen(),
                    );
                  }),
            ],
          ),
//and the rest of the other routing code goes here

Simple as it is.
Screenshot of the problem:

I'm expecting a result of readable strings such as "/cart/checkout-p1" or something, but as shown in the image, it resulted in "gbxlxxpquh\bspcuo]u^ij\dyawt_b`" instead.
If it helps, I'm using go_router: 12.1.1
Could someone kindly point me in the right direction as to why this happened?
Things I've tried:

added key: state.pageKey to pageBuilder, still same result


I think state.pageKey.value is not intended to be a human-readable string. It’s an automatically generated unique identifier for each page. This is why you’re seeing what appears to be gibberish.
state.pageKey is used internally and it’s not meant to represent the route in a human-readable format. If you need to get the current route as a string, you should use state.location.
Try printing the route for debugging purposes, you can use debugPrint(state.location) instead of debugPrint(state.pageKey.value). This will print the current route in the console in a readable format like “/cart/checkout-p1”.

Thanks for letting me know state.pageKey.value is not intended to readable.
After some googling, state.location seems to be deprecated, and replaced by GoRouterState.of(context).uri.toString();
Source: link
Also, state.pageKey could result in the same route showing different page key (same page, but different keys,, which is what I want), whereas GoRouterState.of(context).uri.toString(); (look at #1) will result in the same route location no matter what.

My mistake, GoRouterState.of(context).uri.toString() is indeed the recommended way to get the current route's URI as a readable string in the latest GoRouter versions.
You're also correct about the behavior of state.pageKey: it's designed to be unique even for the same route if the navigation state differs. This is helpful for managing page state, but not ideal for simple route logging.

Try to implement this example:
class CheckoutScreen extends StatelessWidget {
const CheckoutScreen({super.key});
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final state = GoRouterState.of(context);
debugPrint("URI: ${state.uri.toString()}"); // Outputs: /cart/checkout
// ... your other code

}
}
Points to remember:
GoRouterState.of(context).uri.toString() provides a clean, readable representation of the route.
state.pageKey is for internal GoRouter management and isn't designed for user-facing displays.
